# How to search for approximate word in database

Tags: postgresql

My client's requirement is, search and get the results for the word if he types approximately closely matching word from the DB.

Eg. He searches for `Gogle`, it should return `Google` OR if he searches for `GOOOgle`, it should return `Google`.

What I know is `LIKE` will definitely not going to work.But not sure  how can I achieve this.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html

Comment: No, full text search won't do that. Read up on [trigram indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding extension - 
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS fuzzystrmatch;

Then using some variation of levenshtein to see how closely the word matches eg
SELECT levenshtein('GUMBO', 'GAMBOL', 2,1,1);  --- gives result = 3

I'm sure a bit of research into this area will meet your requirement